# Grails 3 reverse engineer database to domain objects

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is there a way to reverse engineer database tables to domain classes in Grails 3? The db-reverse-engineer does not look to be up to date as of this moment, so are there any other solutions?

Comment: Have you really tried using it?

Comment: You can try doing the reverse engineering in a Grails 2 project and then copy the generated domain classes to your Grails 3 project. I also did not find the plugin on bintray.

Comment: I have tried using it. Yeah, I can do it on a Grails 2 project - I was just curious if there were any current ways of doing it in a Grails 3 project, but it doesn't look like it :)